# Getting an error in Proteus while simulating the following circuit

Tags: simulation, proteus, error, band-pass

I have built a circuit with a series of bandpass filters to detect specific frequencies.

While simulating the circuit on Proteus, I was getting the following error. I tried looking for a solution to it on the internet, but could not seem to understand what exactly is wrong.

Could someone help me with it, please?

[image: error messages]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Why so many inputs in parallel? Also change all 220 values to >=1k

Comment: If those inputs are voltage sources then you are connecting them all in parallel -- you can't do that because their internal resistance is zero. Similarly for series curent sources.

Comment: Hi @aconcernedcitizen , those are square wave frequency generators connected in parallel. I am trying to simulate different frequencies being superimposed on each other and then trying to filter them out using bandpass filters.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Those are square wave frequency generators connected in parallel. I am trying to simulate different frequencies being superimposed on each other and then trying to filter them out using bandpass filters.

Comment: Without a source resistance you are violating laws of voltage sources

Comment: @DevanshS It sounds like you're interested in an `.AC` analysis, not `.TRAN`. For that you only need one source with `AC 1`, but if you insist in having different sources in `.TRAN`, then you have to either add series resistances for each source, or stack the (voltage) sources, or use current sources all connected to one shunt resistor.